# Неправильно работает console.log() в google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, консоль, логирование

Простейший пример прикреплен. Вот результат его работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Консоль сразу после инициализации пустого массива пишет, что там есть элемент.
Но если выводить напрямую длинну массива - выводит 0.

Еще вчера вроде было все нормально. Комп перезагружал.
Как пофиксить?

Chrome 60.0.3112.90. 
OS X 10.11.6

```js
const arr =[];
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
arr.push(0);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это не баг. В arr передается ссылка на массив, поэтому  когда вы нажимаете на стрелку в консоли система проходит по ссылке на массив и отображается текущие состояние массива. Поэтому о промежуточных состояниях массива можно судить только по текстовым меткам, либо можно создавать копии текущего состояния массива при вывод в консоль с помощью `arr.slice("")`. А `console.log(arr.length)` вы выводите до момента добавления элемента, вот он и выдает 0. 
Вот вам пример:
[image: Скрин консоли]

```js
const arr =[];
console.log("Обычный вывод:",arr);
console.log("Slice вывод:",arr.slice(""));
arr.push(0);
console.log("Обычный вывод:",arr);
console.log("Slice вывод:",arr.slice(""));
arr.push(1);
arr.push(2);
```

Comment: Я, конечно, подозревал про ссылку, но до последнего надеялся, что это баг. По логике, если пользователь логирует массив, то он хочет увидеть его состояние на момент логирования, а не на момент просмотра...
А можно как-нибудь легально увидеть состояние массива именно на момент логирования? Без splice() и прочих хаков.

Comment: Добавил про хак с arr.slice(""), легальных методов к сожалению не знаю((

Answer (score 0):

> console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. в частности, стоит изложить, каким именно образом написанное вами отвечает на вопрос.